# What are the advantages of "enum class" over simple "enum" once there is std::underlying_type_t?

Tags: c++, enums, c++14

`enum class` is aiming to provide type safety, thus eliminating implicit conversion to integer by integral promotion, but once we have `std::underlying_type_t` the advantage of `enum class` is not clear to me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `enum` (without `class`) does _not_ provide type safety, while `enum class` does. You have always been able to _explicitly_ cast to the underlying type, but `std::underlying_type_t` doesn't suddenly reintroduce _implicit_ casts (which `enum class` is designed to prevent)...

Comment: Your question is the answer... _explicitly_ is the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The are two major differences between `enum` and `enum class`:

1. `enum class` doesn't allow implicit conversion between `enum class` value and underlying type. Yes, you can do an explicit conversion but it won't happen automatically.
2. `enum class` introduces a new scope.

```
enum Enum
{
    Value1,
    Value2 // <- both values are accessible without `Enum::`
}

enum class EnumClass
{
    Value1,
    Value2 // <- values are accessible only with `EnumClass::` prefix
}
```